# taking value to next 10th position

Tags: php

I know that it's rather an unusual question, but I need to find next 10th position

Let me clear with an example:

I will have some numbers like

```
2, 5, 8, 13, 28, 35, 42, 49
```

I want to find the next 10th position

```
2  =>  10
5  =>  10
8  =>  10
13  =>  20
28  =>  30
35  =>  40
42  =>  50
49  =>  50
```

How can I find it, please help guys. thanks.

Sorry for poor english.

Comment: I think in English that is generally referred to as "the 10s position". Just trying to help.

Comment: So you want to round up to the nearest multiple of ten.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$next10th = round( $number + 5 , -1 ,  PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN )
```

If the number is integer, you can also use:

```
$next10th = $number + 9 - (($number-1) % 10)
```

Comment: +1 I'd use either of these in preference to a solution using `ceil()` or `floor()`.

Answer (score 8):

Divide by 10, [`ceil()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ceil.php), multiply by 10.

Comment: +1 good answer. however I'd prefer to do it without needing any floating points, even if only temporarily, so I'd favour an approach using modulus rather than `ceil()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$numbers = array(2, 5, 8, 13, 28, 35, 42, 49);
foreach ($numbers as $n) {
  echo $n . ' => ' . ((floor($n / 10) + 1) * 10) . "<br />\n";
  }
```

or

```
$numbers = array(2, 5, 8, 13, 28, 35, 42, 49);
foreach ($numbers as $n) {
  echo $n . ' => ' . (ceil($n / 10) * 10) . "<br />\n";
  }
```

Both output:

```
2 => 10
5 => 10
8 => 10
13 => 20
28 => 30
35 => 40
42 => 50
49 => 50
```